# Why do I get two different Project Context for my Spring mvc web application?

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc, web

Following is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="Page on apache.org" xmlns:xsi="Page on w3.org"
xsi:schemaLocation="Welcome to Apache Maven/POM/4.0.0 Page on apache.org">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.MyStartUp.www</groupId>
<artifactId>MyStartUp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>MyStartUp Maven Webapp</name>
<url>Welcome to Apache Maven</url>
<properties>
<spring.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>

</properties>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>3.8.1</version>
<scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
<version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
<version>${spring.version}</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
<version>1.6.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>3.1.0</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
<artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
<version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
<artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
<version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
<artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
<version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
<artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
<version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
<artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
<version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
<finalName>MyStartUp</finalName>

<pluginManagement>
<plugins>
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.1</version>
<configuration>
<source>1.6</source>
<target>1.6</target>
</configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</pluginManagement>
</build>
</project>
```

I use tomcat server v7.0 to deploy and I use maven to build.

Whenever I make a change I go to maven terminal and use "mvn clean install" and go to `localhost:8080/manager` and deploy the war by browsing the application in my desktop. After this I see "MyStartUp" in tomcat manager window in browser.

My project name in eclipse looks as "mystartup".

When I add the project in Eclipse IDE using "Add or remove" after right click the server, I see "mystartup" and I add it. Then if I refresh `localhost:8080/manager/`

I see two different project deployed. 
1) MyStartUp  (Url : localhost:8080/MyStartUp --> Works)
2) mystartup  (Url : localhost:8080/mystartup --> Doesn't Work)

When I click the second one, I am not able to access the application. But if I use the first one, it works

Because of this, each time, I do "mvn clean install" in IDE and I manually undeploy "MyStartUp" and deploy new install of "MyStartUp". This takes away my time. I want to add my project to Server in IDE and restart it when I make a change and run the application. How to fix this issue?

PS:

Here is my web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.2" id="WebApp_ID">

    <!-- <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name> -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/mvc/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/template.jsp</welcome-file>  
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

This is how my git clone looks

git clone https://MyStartUp@bitbucket.org/MyStartUp/mystartup.git

Comment: Can you post your web.xml?

Comment: @lkrnac posted web.xml.

Comment: Are you importing the mvn project in your eclipse?

Comment: Yes.I first did git clone, then mvn eclipse:eclipse, then I import the project to Eclipse.

Comment: Git clone link is dead. You should be able to run the project in eclipse. It depends on the version of eclipse ide. To run the mvn web project you can use kapler or the latest luna. It works fine.

Comment: So, I actually developed the project in Mac book and I commit to Git. Then I cloned in my Windows machine and when I tried to build I have this problem. Also in my Windows machine I am not able to see the war after building the project.

Comment: @PradeepKrKaushal If you don't mind could you answer this question. Please. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229453/why-cant-i-use-valid-parameter-along-with-requestparam-in-spring-mvc